# How can I modify the config file (/proc/config.gz) in linux (Android)?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, config, kernel-module, cgroups

***EDITED: I found that We cannot edit this file, We have to recompile the kernel***
I am installing docker on Android. there are some configurations related to ***cgroup*** which are not enabled. I could find it by extracting the file ***/proc/config.gz***. now it seems i have to ***modify*** the file. it seems we can write some kernel modules for it or i have to recompile the kernel. I am not familiar with low level issues so please help me through this problem.
Thanks

EDITED
based on the file these two parts seems need to be enabled.

#CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE is not set

#CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS is not set

Comment: `/proc/config.gz` is just a copy of the config file that was used to compile the kernel.  You can't change it, you can only compile a new kernel with a different configuration.  See, for instance, https://linuxconfig.org/in-depth-howto-on-linux-kernel-configuration.  Some features can be added by loading modules but not all.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your response. i edited the question. Do you know about these configurations, Can i enable them by modules. i reed in some pages it is possible. but i dont  know how exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I modify the config file (/proc/config.gz) in linux (Android)?

You would have to recompile your own kernel with different configuration and modify your operating system by updating the kernel.

`/proc/config.gz` is a compressed **copy** of the kernel configuration that **was** used when the kernel was build. To modify kernel configuration you have to recompile the kernel.

Comment: Thanks but I dont have enough knowledge about it, would you tell me how should I do that, at least briefly. my kernel version is 4.9 of x_86 android. it is some how new kernel not old. but i dont know how to get new kernel or recompile mine? appreciate

Comment: Well, recompiling kernel is a hard job that takes a few hours (depending on the processor speed) of only compilation. Then flashing new kernel to android is a hard job that for whole forums exists on how to do it without bricking your device. If you really want to, there is a lot of reading ahead of you. There are many, many links available over the net on how to configure and build the kernel and linux documentation is very broad. Big problems are sum of smaller problems: first find the kernel sources that your device uses, then download those sources, then configure, then....

Comment: Really [the first link on google I found](https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/customize_kernel.html) after [search x86 android kernel](https://www.google.com/search?q=x_86+android+kernel)..